# Neural Network for regression with one dependent and one independent variable

Tags: neural-network, tensorflow, regression

I am trying to make a simple neural network with one dependent and one independent variable. Could you maybe give me a tutorial or help me with the implementation of a neural network with one dependent and one independent variable. So far I have the following code, however my predictions are not good although the error is minimized. Should I scale X and Y or do I have some mistake?

Thank you in advance

```
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x=[(i*i)+0.2 for i in range(1000)]
y=[i for i in range(1000)]

x_train=np.reshape(x,(-1,1))
y_train=np.reshape(y,(-1,1))
x_test=x_train[:,-10:]
y_test=y_train[:,-10:]
plt.scatter(x_train,y_train)
plt.show()


X=tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,1])
Y=tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,1])

n_inputs=1
n_hidden_1=20
n_hidden_2=20
n_outputs=1

weights={
    "h1": tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_inputs,n_hidden_1])),
    "h2": tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_1,n_hidden_2])),
    "out": tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_2,n_outputs]))
}

biases={
    "b1": tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_1])),
    "b2": tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_2])),
    "out": tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_outputs]))
}

def neural_net(x):
    layer_1=tf.add(tf.matmul(x,weights["h1"]),biases["b1"])
    layer_1=tf.nn.relu(layer_1)
    layer_2=tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_1,weights["h2"]),biases["b2"])
    layer_2=tf.nn.relu(layer_2)
    layer_3=tf.matmul(layer_2,weights["out"])+biases["out"]
    return layer_3

Y_pred=neural_net(X)

loss=tf.losses.mean_squared_error(X,Y_pred)
optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.01)
train_op=optimizer.minimize(loss)

epochs=1000
init=tf.global_variables_initializer()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    for i in range(epochs):
        sess.run(train_op,feed_dict={X:x_train,Y:y_train})
        loss_op=sess.run(loss,feed_dict={X:x_train,Y:y_train})
        if i%10==0:
            print("Epoch "+str(i)+" loss "+str(loss_op))
    pred=sess.run(Y_pred,feed_dict={X:x_test})
    plt.plot(pred,color="red")
    plt.plot(y_test,color="blue")
    plt.show()
    plt.scatter(pred,y_test)
    plt.show()
    for i in range(len(pred)):
        print(str(pred[i])+" "+str(y_test[i]))
```

Comment: If you just want to make a simple neural network with one dependent and one independent variable, I would suggest to use scikit-learn instead of tensorflow.

Comment: I would ideally extend it to a recursive neural network but I wanted to start with something.

Comment: Try shuffling your data before train test split. One reason might be that you are using bigger values in test than in train.

Answer (score 0):

Your predictions are not actually that bad. At the very last line of your code, print the expected value too at each line (that is x_test[i]= y_test[i]^2+0.2).

Comment: Shouldn't y_test[i] correspond to pred[i]?

Comment: pred[i] is what your model predicts. You should compare it to the actual results which is calculated as y_test[i]^2+0.2 according to your code.

Comment: or x_test[i] to be clear. That is how x and y are defined.

Comment: One more question, pred[i] should correspond to y_test[i] so my intuition was to compare with that. I want the model to output y_test[i] not x_test[i] or y_test[i]^2+0.2. Since this x_test and y_test will not be defined as is, but will be other numbers, why does the model not output y_test directly? Do I need to normalize or scale them somehow?

Comment: No, it is just related to how things are defined in the given code. We have on lines 5 to 11:

x=[(i*i)+0.2 for i in range(1000)]
y=[i for i in range(1000)]

x_train=np.reshape(x,(-1,1))
y_train=np.reshape(y,(-1,1))
x_test=x_train[:,-10:]
y_test=y_train[:,-10:]

given above. These mean that y is the input and x is the output (output of the calculation y^2 +0.2).

Comment: Nono, x is the input y is the output.

Comment: Oh, I thought otherwise because the loss function is defined as MSE(X,Y_pred). If that is the case this should also be MSE(Y,Y_pred). And as an additional note, the way x_test and y_test defined above is also not correct, check their shape to see the problem. In any case, you want training and test set distinct and shuffled.